# docker login error Error saving credentials in windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

I want to login in my docker hub account and push images to reposibilit
But,when i run docker login -u, I get a error.

Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `Post "https://hub.docker.com/v2/users/login?refresh_token=true": dialing hub.docker.com:443 with direct connection: connecting to 104.244.46.208:443: dial tcp 104.244.46.208:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

how can i slove this error